# change the style of title attribute of the img tag

Tags: html

when we hover on any html tag like anchor tag,img tag etc if we have set the title attribute then it will display its value when we hour the mouse on that tag , my question is that how can i change the styling of that tag like changing its back ground color font color. by default light cream color back gorung and black font display i want to change this 
please tell me how can i do this ?i have no idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't offer a way to style the title text (that I know of), but you could use a [JavaScript based tooltip](http://www.opentip.org/) instead. There are many to choose from and most will be fully customizable to your needs.